# Ping from Objective-C iOS7

Tags: ios, ping

I understand there are multiple solutions already available to do a ping from an iOS application. However, most seem to be outdated, unsupported, or removed by Apple.

I also do not want to use SimplePing library (since it just appears to be bloated and the SimplePingHelper that is available uses selectors which doesn't fit into my application) or the Reachibility.m provided Apple (since it only checks if the path to the service is available, not if the service is actually online). I also found another solution that is now deprecated.

So, does anybody else have any other ideas on how to ping a server?

Comment: Did you Want to Ping a server, or to Check availibility of a service on a server ?

Comment: Just ping an address (not necessarily an IP or just a server) and see if it's online or not.

Comment: You already have the answer; `SimplePing` is your best option. If you don't like how `SimplePingHelper` is implemented, either don't use it or improve it to your needs. Something like the `boost` example below looks much more convoluted than `SimplePing`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at [GBPing](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBPing)?

To quote the doc:

> This code is a low level ping library that gives extremely accurate round-trip timing results without being impacted by UI and other processing on the main thread. This is not the case with most other ping libraries such as the typical Apple SimplePing which are built as a single threaded class interleaved within the main thread of execution, causing them to suffer from all kinds of indeterministic errors. This library is a multi-threaded class built on top of BSD sockets and GCD, delivering the best possible timing accuracy regardless of system resource state or device performance.

Answer (score -1):

There is a [ping example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/icmp/) in the open-source [boost](http://www.boost.org) library. I've managed to compile and run it under OS X. I'm not sure if it would work under iOS.